# Ace template error on js, function ace.general_things

Tags: javascript

Im using this [Template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0B30DGR).

One function of ace.min.js (comes with template) i get an error, i dont know why is this happening. All .js are loaded.

Is the problem in the order? Or what im doing wrong?

Any clue about this will help.

Error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of undefined ace.min.js:11
ace.general_things ace.min.js:11
(anonymous function) ace.min.js:6
l jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
c.fireWith jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery-2.0.3.min.js:4
S`

My layout is this one,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="@Url.Content("~/favicon.ico")" />

    <!--basic styles-->

    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css")" />
    <!-- esta estaba en la validacion de forms -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/select2.css")" />

    <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css")" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--page specific plugin styles-->

    <!--fonts-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/ace-fonts.css")" />

    <!--ace styles-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/ace.min.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/ace-responsive.min.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/ace-skins.min.css")" />

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/css/ace-ie.min.css")" />
    <![endif]-->

    <!--inline styles related to this page-->

    <!--ace settings handler-->

    <!--basic scripts-->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/ace-extra.min.js")" > </script>

</head>

    <body >
    ....

  <!--[if !IE]>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js")" > </script>
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" > </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--
        <script type="text/javascript">

         if ("ontouchend" in document) document.write("<script src='@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js'>" + "<" + "/script>");
    </script>
        -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js")" > </script>

    <!--page specific plugin scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js")"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.reloadAJAX.min.js")" > </script>
    <!--ace scripts-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/ace-elements.min.js")" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/wrap/assets/js/ace.min.js")" > </script>

    <!--inline scripts related to this page-->


</body>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem for me
I resolved it by following this steps :
go to your js/uncompressed folder and you will find ace.js
Open that file and go to the line 121, then comment all the lines from 121 to 131
( All these lines are referencing #ace-setting-* ) 
I imagine that you removed the settings bar from your template so it's referencing inexistant Dom element.

I submitted a more correct workaround to the owner of AceAdmin template. Hope it will be available soon.